# Jquery .Trigger() firing only once

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

When the appropriate button is clicked, a hidden file input is triggered which in part auto submits on .change. Within the change function we vet the file and run an update or return an error.

The problem occurs when an error is fired, so the next time the button is clicked the change function does not seem to work. How could I get this to work if pressed again after the error has been produced. I have tried using die() and unbind() but this has not worked.

```
    //
// Image Upload 1 
//

$('.btn-image-upload').live('tap', function(event) { 
    // Variable
    var id = $(this).attr('id');    
    // Target        
    if (!$(event.target).is('#upload-'+id)) {
        $(this).find('#upload-'+id).trigger('click');
    }
});

//
// Image Upload 2
//

$('.file').live('change', function(event) {

    // Variable
    var id = $(this).attr('id');

    // HTML 5 Checks        
    var file = this.files[0];
    var name = file.name;
    var size = file.size;
    var type = file.type;

    // File Check
    switch(type) {
        case 'image/png': 
        case 'image/gif':
        case 'image/jpg': 
        case 'image/jpeg':
        break;
        default:
        // Error
        $('.btn-image-upload').text('Only Jpg, Png, Gif Allowed');
        // Return
        return false;
    } 

    // Size Check
    if(size > 2097152) {
        // Error
        $('.btn-image-upload').text('File Too Big 2mb Max');
        // Return
        return false;
    } 


});
```

Comment: use `on` instead of `live` if you are using newer version of jQuery library (1.7+)

Comment: When there is an error, the content of .btn-image-upload is replaced with the text message, then the file input it simply deleted. So you should place the text message into another div or place the file input out of the .btn-image-upload.

Comment: @Codel96 You are completely right, I feel like an idiot. I guess this highlights the fact that I need to take more breaks away from the screen.